# How do you embed video in Grafana?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, grafana

I am trying to embed an MP4 into a Grafana dashboard on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have entered this into the "text" dashboard in HTML mode.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="/home/testing/Downloads/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This shows the controls but does not show the video. When I put the same code in an html page on its own, however, the video shows as expected.

I have also placed a video in `/var/www/html` but this fails to show too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that source is correct: `src="/home/testing/Downloads/video.mp4"`? It tries to load video from the Grafana server. Make sure, that your video is available via http/https protocol.

Comment: The video is located in `/home/testing/Downloads/video.mp4` but I can move it. Where should it go?

Comment: Move it to /var/www/html and if your web server is serving this location just change the source to  ```src="/video.mp4"``` or server from grafanan public folder

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the correct way to do this would be to move the video into the grafana public folder and serve it from there.

On the grafana server, move the video to `/usr/share/grafana/public/video` , you will have to create this folder first (owned by root and perms 755)

Then within the panel, your html would simply be

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="/public/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

All script type tags were disabled in a previous version of Grafana for security purposes. To enable them, un-comment this line in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` - it's near the bottom.

```
;disable_sanitize_html = false
```

Then set it to true

```
disable_sanitize_html = true
```

Worth bearing in mind that this could be a **significant security risk**. Do so at your own risk.

This will enable the `video` tag as well as `iframe`, so you will also be able to embed YouTube videos. Unfortunately, I have not been successful in getting either local or YouTube video to loop, so YouTube live streams seem to be the best bet. I currently have a Grafana dashboard playing Sky News, for example.

As @tomgalpin has noted, you can put a video file in `/usr/share/grafana/public/video` so that Grafana can serve it. I'd stick with YouTube if possible though.

Answer (score 0):

In a panel plugin, put your mp4 in `src/img/` and use this in your ReactJs component:

```
<video src="/public/plugins/your-plugin-name/img/sample-mp4-file.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls loop></video>
```